# How to update a manytomany field in Django without deleting the previous object?

Tags: python, django

I have seen this question before, but mine is a bit more restricted in terms of getting the object and filtering.

**EDIT** - **Removed relationship between member and title and changed member and xmlgraph to one to many relationship**

I have these classes in models.py:

```
class Title(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class XMLGraph(models.Model):
    #only one title per graph
    title = models.OneToOneField(
        to=Title,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    XMLGraph = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.XMLGraph)

class Member(User):

    XMLGraph = models.ForeignKey('XMLGraph',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        to=Member,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

One **Member** can store multiple **XMLGraphs** which are basically text files stored in the database. I have a functionality where the user can save and save as the **XMLGraph**.

The save function should create a new object of the **XMLGraph** if there is nothing in the database or update the current **XMLGraph**. So, when the user presses save, it should update the data stored in the **XMLGraph**. So, I took this approach:

**Save function in views.py**

```
def saveData(request, user):
    if request.method == "POST":
        xmlData = request.POST['xml']
        member = Member.objects.get(username=user)
        XMLGraph.objects.all().delete()
        xml, _ = XMLGraph.objects.get_or_create(XMLGraph = xmlData)
        member.XMLGraph.add(xml)
        return render_to_response("fastcookapp/index.html", content_type="text/xml;")
    return HttpResponse('POST is not used')
```

However, now the issue is that the **Save As** function should generate a new object for **XMLGraph** and **Title** which works fine, but once they click the **save** function it will delete the previous data for **XMLGraph** because of the following line in **saveData**

```
XMLGraph.objects.all().delete()
```

**Save As in views.py**:

```
@loggedin
def saveAs(request, user):
if request.method == "POST":
    member = Member.objects.get(username=user)
    graphTitle = request.POST['title']
    title = Title.objects.create(title=graphTitle)
    member.title.add(title)
    xmlData = request.POST['xml']
    xml = XMLGraph.objects.create(XMLGraph = xmlData, title=title)
    member.XMLGraph.add(xml)
    return render_to_response("fastcookapp/index.html", content_type="text/xml;")
return HttpResponse('POST is not used')
```

I am aware of .remove() being used instead of delete, but it doesn't seem to work properly as I can't remove the previous data that was added when the user presses **save**.

Comment: I really don't understand your code. Why call delete if you don't want to delete them? But why have a m2m at all when the relationship is one-to-many? You should have a foreign key from XMLGraph to User. And the title relationships are even more broken.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman the reason i’m deleting it, is because you can’t update m2m fields with update() so i’m deleting the previously stored data from the user so it stores new data. One XMLGraph should have One title, what’s wrong with that relationship?

Comment: Your justification mages even less sense. Of course you can update ah existing instance. And I was referring to the extra relationship between Member and Title. Also you didn't address my point that the relationship between graph and member should be many to one, not many to many.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Oh yes, you are right about member and title, that should not be included I will remove that. Thanks. Also, I was a bit confused about the graph and member relationship, I initially assumed it was a one to many relationship, but thought it would not matter I will also change this. How do you update an existing instance now in a one to many relationship for the specific field.